# Problem with analysis with special characters in getsymbols (PerformanceAnalytics)

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to create a chart.correlation with the package PerformanceAnalytics. This works great like here:

```
if(!require("PerformanceAnalytics")) {install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics"); require("PerformanceAnalytics")}
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
#
getSymbols("AMZN",from="2016-01-01",to="2020-05-01")
getSymbols("TSLA",from="2016-01-01",to="2020-05-01")
data1<-cbind(diff(log(Cl(AMZN))),diff(log(Cl(TSLA))))
chart.Correlation(data1)
```

But as soon as there are special characters I get the following error:

Error: unexpected '^' in "data<-cbind(diff(log(Cl(UTDI.DE))),diff(log(Cl(^"

for the following code:

```
getSymbols("UTDI.DE",from="2016-01-01",to="2020-05-01")
getSymbols("^MDAXI",from="2016-01-01",to="2020-05-01")
data2<-cbind(diff(log(Cl(UTDI.DE))),diff(log(Cl(^MDAXI))))
chart.Correlation(data2)
```

Does anyone know how to use the special character here?

Comment: use `data2<-cbind(diff(log(Cl(UTDI.DE))),diff(log(Cl(MDAXI)))` without the ^ in front of MDAXI. getSymbols autoassign removes the ^ when creating the object. Tip: Do not use the autoassign, but assign the variable names yourself.

Comment: thank you. i tried it once wihtout the ^ but then i had another error. now it works. thanks!